# A more elegant and efficient way to transfer state from one instance to another

Tags: java, pointers

Hermione is recovering from the Battle of Hogwarts and studying object-oriented programming with Java (go figure). She decides to build a game based on her experiences
and identifies the following major entities:

A human is a being. A wizard is also a human.

A house elf is a being.

A ghost is a being.

She then identifies some state and actions:

Every being has a name.

Every human has a father and a mother.

Every wizard performs magic.

Every house elf also performs magic.

Every ghost glides to some location.

Turning a wizard into a ghost can be achieved by copying all relevant state from
the wizard instance to the newly created ghost instance. What is a more elegant
and efficient approach?

Could I just make the new created Ghost instance point to the state the Wizard instance pointed to and then delete the wizard instance? Sorry for my bad English, I had trouble writing the title

Comment: is this a homework question? If so please be honest and tag it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't support pointers

You can't delete an instance.

You can have the Ghost instance reference the Wizard instance.  However I suspect this is homework and when you do homework, you need to get the expected answer not just one which works, so I suggest you copy the details as you have been told to.

Is efficiency a requirement?  I suspect performance is not something you need to worry about in this assignment.  If it is an issue can you say what the performance requirement is?

Answer (score 0):

The ghost and the wizard should have some common data, you encapsulate this in an own class. When you make a ghost out of a wizard, you just reference to this common data in your ghost. You remove all the references to the wizard, when you run garbage collection, then the wizard will be "gone forever".